# Extend and customize a performance monitor

Tags: windows, profiling, performance

.NET has several built in Perfmons, and I would like to know is it possible to extend one of the built in ones and add custom functionality.

More specifically, I would like to take RateOfCountsPerSecond32 and make it be something such as RateOfCountsPerMinute.  Basically I would like to be able to monitor the average number of events that happen in a given time, but longer than a second.

Is extending the right idea? If so does anyone have a quick syntax example of how it can be done? I have read that it can be done but documentation is super poor on the subject.  Or is there a better way to go about this entirely, very open to suggestions.

Thanks for any help,